# How to import existing S3 bucket from another stack in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'd like to import an existing S3 bucket that is created in another stack. I tried to do it using two CF templates below but when I try to create a consumer stack it leads to a CREATE_FAILED event with an "already exists" error message.

Producer template:

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Main stack that creates S3 bucket.",
"Resources": {
"myS3Bucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
      "Properties": {"BucketName": "bucket-name" }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "BucketId": {
        "Description": "Bucket ID",
        "Value": { "Ref": "myS3Bucket" },
        "Export": { "Name": { "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-BUCKETID" }}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a consumer stack template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template.",
    "Resources" : { 
        "S3ImportedBucket" : {  
            "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties" : {
                "BucketName" : { "Fn::ImportValue" : "main-BUCKETID"} 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should be changed in the templates to make it work?

Comment: This is a very bad idea, and I'm not even sure if its possible to have two stacks managed same resource. What would you like to achieve? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Marcin Basically trying to use a bucket in another stack to do things like policy assignment (so that service from consumer stack could access that bucket) and so on.

Comment: Sadly you can't do this the way you are trying. Instead, like the answer posted, you export output from one stack, then reference it using `ImportValue`.

Comment: Yeah, too many limitations with the resource import in CF.

Comment: @Cybex Were you able to solve it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**:
the concept of [outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) is right but you are using it in a wrong way

**explanation**
In cloudformation templates, you are posting

Both create a resource of s3 bucket type with the same name so whatever runs first will create the s3 bucket

you can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) for reference

however, the output can be used as a reference in other templates like if you are uploading something from lambda so you can set that bucket as env var and use it inside the lambda (just an example)

Comment: I understand why I get this error message. I am looking for a fix that would allow me to import existing bucket into another stack (cross-stack reference). The available tutorials don't have suitable examples (most have something real simple like getting text values).

Comment: check the outputs of cloudformation that's the way to reference resource across stacks

Comment: also when you use the bucket as a reference in other place check what the other place want 
does it want the resource name or the resource ARN  and based on that edit your outputs

Comment: OK, I'll check out Outputs documentation.Thank you!